# How to execute ruby function with attributes using AJAX request in Rails 6.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I have the following home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @data = EmergencyFriend.all
    @jsonData = JSON.pretty_generate(@data.as_json)
  end

  def about
  end

  def alertEmergencyContant
    account_sid = "my id"
    auth_token = "my token"

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

    @client.messages.create(
        to: "+number 1",
        from: "+number 2",
        body: "hello world !"
    )
  end
end
```

Basically, in my `home/index.html.erb` there is only one button. When the button is pressed it shows an alert message that allows user to select an option to send an SMS to.

[image: IMAGE DEMO]

What I want to do is to call the `alertEmergencyContant` method in my home controller so that I can send the message. I also want to pass the phone_number as a parameter with that request. It has been suggested that for this I should use AJAX. I successfully installed jquery and ajax in my rails project and works as expected. What I can't understand is how to create it as a POST request.

My routes list for the home directory are :

```
root       GET       /                          home#index
root       GET       /home/about(.:format)      home#about
```

But there is nothing on `alertEmergencyContant`. How to declare that in the routes and make it as a POST request? How to pass attributes from JavaScript to ruby using AJAX?

Here is my ajax request so far (This works):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(event){
        alert("sending Message");
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
def about   
    @thisNumber = params[:phone_number] 
    puts "helllloooooooooooooo        " + @thisNumber
end
```

```
function ajaxRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'home/about/?phone_number:1244211',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(event){
            alert("passed");
        },
        failed: function(){
            alert("has failed")
        },
        done: function(){
            alert("after")
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a route to your action

```rb
# routes.rb 
post 'some_url' => 'home#alert_emergency_contact'
```

You can now use this in your javascript

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/some_url', // This needs to match what you choose in routes.rb
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(event){
        alert("sending Message");
    }
});
```

---

PS: Action names are always_snake_case in Ruby, not camelCase